# Converting hex to string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, hex, converters, bitconverter

Hello I am using digi dynamic c. I am trying to convert this in to string

```
char readingreg[4];
readingreg[0] = 4a;
readingreg[1] = aa;
readingreg[2] = aa;
readingreg[3] = a0;
```

Currently when I do `printf` statements it has to be like this:

```
printf("This is element 0: %x\n", readingreg[0]);
```

But I want this in string so I can use `printf` statement like this

```
  printf("This is element 0: %s\n", readingreg[0]);
```

I am essentialy sending the readingreg array over TCP/IP Port, for which I need to have it as string. I cant seem to be able to convert it into string. Thanks for your help.
Also if someone can tell me how to do each element at a time rather than whole array, that would be fine to since there will only be 4 elements.

Comment: Please clarify, what exactly to you want the second printf() to print.

Comment: [inet_ntoa()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa)

Comment: Use `snprintf` to print to a buffer, then print that? Also remember the string terminating 0 byte.

Comment: Looking at answers i dont think i was clear, sorry. So essentialy i have an array which is readingreg (char) but has hex values. I want its values to be string. For example: readingreg[0] = 4a, 4a is hex value can someone help me in making a new array and it would look like: newArray[0] = 4a; newArray[1] = aa; and so on where 4a and aa will be strings rather than hex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0xaa` overflows when plain `char` is `signed`, use `unsigned char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char readingreg[4];
    readingreg[0] = 0x4a;
    readingreg[1] = 0xaa;
    readingreg[2] = 0xaa;
    readingreg[3] = 0xa0;
    char temp[4];

    snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "%x", readingreg[0]);
    printf("This is element 0: %s\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gives an error. `pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]`. Probably it is a warning but I have `Werror` on.

Comment: Are you sure? there are not pointers involved in this code and I'm compiling with stricts warnings (`-Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs`) and `gcc` compiles silently without warnings this piece of code. Same for godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/9h7rEP no warnings. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: If I change the data type of `temp` to `char`, then I do not get any errors. I have gcc8.3.0 on Debian 10. Thank you for the prompt update. The `unsigned char` data type is important only for the variable storing the byte-array, where using a `char` could cause an overflow.

Comment: You are welcome, _I have gcc8.3.0 on Debian 10_ - that's odd, I'm also on Debian 10 and I don't receive any warning, same on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @DavidRanieri My bad I misread the intent of the code. I'll delete my comments soon to keep this clean.

Answer (score 2):

If your machine is big endian, you can do the following:

```
char str[9];

sprintf(str, "%x", *(uint32_t *)readingreg);
```

If your machine is little endian you'll have to swap the byte order:

```
char str[9];
uint32_t host;

host = htonl(*(uint32_t *)readingreg);
sprintf(str, "%x", host);
```

If portability is a concern, you should use method two regardless of your endianness.

I get the following output:

```
printf("0x%s\n", str);
```

> 0x4aaaaaa0