# C - converting hex to string

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

Following on an old question [Converting hex to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630947/converting-hex-to-string-in-c)

The approved answer suggests to use sprintf to convert each hex to string.

I have two question on this -

1) When i have a hex like `0a` i want my string to have `0a` too, but following the above solution the result will have `a`.

2) What am i doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char readingreg[10];
    readingreg[0] = 0x4a;
    readingreg[1] = 0xab;
    readingreg[2] = 0xab;
    readingreg[3] = 0x0a;
    readingreg[4] = 0x40;
    unsigned char temp[10];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5)
    {
        sprintf(temp + i, "%x", readingreg[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("String: %s\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

The o/p seems to - `String: 4aaa40`

3) Combining both the both questions, i want my result string to be `4aabab0a40`

TIA

Comment: `sprintf(temp + 2*i, "%02x", readingreg[i]);` And: `unsigned char temp[10+1];` (But it is better to use the return value from sprintf() ,or: even use snprintf())

Comment: 1) Is no question. 3) is no question. 2) is out of scope of SO.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several problems.

First `unsigned char temp[10];` should be `unsigned char temp[11];` to contain a string terminator.

Next is the format spec `"%x"` should be `"%02x"` so each value is 2 digits.

Then `temp + i` should be `temp + i*2` so each pair of digits is written in the right place.

Correcting those mistakes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char readingreg[10];
    readingreg[0] = 0x4a;
    readingreg[1] = 0xab;
    readingreg[2] = 0xab;
    readingreg[3] = 0x0a;
    readingreg[4] = 0x40;
    unsigned char temp[11];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5)
    {
        sprintf(temp + i*2, "%02x", readingreg[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("String: %s\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output is now the required

```
String: 4aabab0a40
```

Comment: Are arrays to be used as make-believe strings not supposed to be the compiler defaults' `char` type?

Comment: @usr2564301 the compiler's default `char` type may well be unsigned. Strings in C are "make-believe" if you like, C has no string type. They are arrays with a nul terminator.

Comment: It is of no consequence for OP's code or your answer, but still :) The usual prototypes for string functions mention just `char`, that is, they *do* adhere to the compiler default. That's why I mentioned it, as a warning for OP – a manual override to *either* `signed` or `unsigned` may trigger warnings.