# Convert HEX to printable string/char

Tags: c++, c, debugging, winapi, cng

I'm using [CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-portal) to generate a hash.
Result of [BCryptFinishHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptfinishhash) call is MD5 of a input in hex form.
Example:

```
char *outHash = "\x02\x34\x75\01..."
```

I want to convert it to printable string: 02347501...

How can I do that?

Comment: `sprintf` will do. With `%02x`.

Comment: C or C++, they are different languages.

Comment: can use [`CryptBinaryToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use [`CryptBinaryToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringw) here with `CRYPT_STRING_HEXASCII` or `CRYPT_STRING_HEX` or `CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW` or `CRYPT_STRING_HEX | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF` or `CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF` depen how you want format string. for example

```
void print(PUCHAR pbHash, ULONG cbHash, DWORD dwFlags = CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF)
{
    ULONG cch = 0;
    if (CryptBinaryToStringW(pbHash, cbHash, dwFlags, 0, &cch))
    {
        if (PWSTR sz = (PWSTR)_malloca(cch * sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            if (CryptBinaryToStringW(pbHash, cbHash, dwFlags, sz, &cch))
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);
            }
            _freea(sz);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To encode a byte array in hex and write the encoded data to a `std::string`, do this:

```
static inline char
hex_digit(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n < 10) return '0' + n;
    if (n < 16) return 'a' + (n - 10);
    abort();
}

std::string
encode_bytes(const unsigned char *bytes, size_t len)
{
    std::string rv;
    rv.reserve(len * 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rv.push_back(hex_digit((bytes[i] & 0xF0) >> 4));
        rv.push_back(hex_digit((bytes[i] & 0x0F) >> 0));
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Note that you *must* know the length of the byte array.  It is not safe to treat it as a NUL-terminated "C string", because binary data can contain internal zero bytes.  To know the length of a hash generated by CNG, call [BCryptGetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/5c62ca3a-843e-41a7-9340-41785fbb15f4) to get the `BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easy, one time solution, this is a useful tool:
https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

However, if you're looking to do this within your code itself, I found this from an earlier thread (AKA, this is not my work but that of @[KEINE LUST](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606345/keine-lust) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25631337) )

> ```
> int main(void)
> {
> unsigned char readingreg[4];
> readingreg[0] = 0x4a;
> readingreg[1] = 0xaa;
> readingreg[2] = 0xaa;
> readingreg[3] = 0xa0;
> char temp[4];
>
> sprintf(temp, "%x", readingreg[0]);
> printf("This is element 0: %s\n", temp);
> return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: If this is copied material please link to where it was copied from and quote the code.

Comment: here you go friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630947/converting-hex-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can print it like this:

```
for(const char *wsk=outHash; *wsk; ++wsk){
    printf("%02hhx", *wsk);
}
```

**Edit based that cstring can have 0x00 numbers.**

C

```
const char outHash[] = "\x02\x34\x75";
const int size = sizeof(outHash)/sizeof(char) - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    printf("%02hhx", outHash [i]);
}
```

C++

```
std::string outHash = "\x02\x34\x75";
for(int i = 0; i < outHash.size(); ++i) {
    printf("%02hhx", outHash [i]);
}
```

Comment: BTW `hh` is not really needed, as in variadic functions all signed (unsigned) integral types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (`unsigned int`) anyway. You can use straight `"%02x"`, write less and remain compatible with older compilers.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil hhx is for unsigned char if we want to display it as hex number. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ watch this site flags and below you have length specifiers

Comment: This has a fairly serious bug: the binary form of a cryptographic hash is _not_ a NUL-terminated string and may contain internal 0x00 bytes.

Comment: Then you need only change *wsk as checking size of string but if this was c++ I would use std::string as container. If c and string have 0x00 chars I would have to sizeof(outHash)/sizeof(char) to get numbers of characters.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `hh` is useful when `outHash[]` have have negative values.  Else one can get output like `FFFFFF80` rather than `80`.

Comment: @chux: aah right, I always avoided the problem by storing byte-data in `unsigned char` arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How is `hhx` not a correct match for `char`? Spec says "hh 
  Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
signed char or unsigned char argument".

Comment: @MichałMarszałek: The issue is not what we want the display to be but whether the argument matches the conversion specification. If you pass an `int` for `%x`, the behavior is undefined, because `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. The fact that you are asking it to display in hexadecimal is irrelevant; there are requirements that the arguments match the specifiers. However, chux may be right that `%hhx` is flexible and can accept either a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought that way too, yet the spec does appears quite explicit in allowing either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "If you pass an int for %x, the behavior is undefined"  §6.5.2.2 6 excepts that when the `int` is positive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187292/discussion-between-chux-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the characters and print the numerical value (in hex).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char*  outHash = "\x02\x34\x75\x01\x23\xff";  // Get from your Hash function.
    int    sizeOfHash = 6;                        // Use appropriate size for BCryptFinishHash()


    // Set up the characteristics of the stream.
    // setw(2):       Each printed object will use a min width of 2
    // setfill('0'):  If the object is less than 2 char then fill the space with '0'
    // hex:           Print numbers in hex.
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;

    // Create a view of the object.
    // Makes it simpler to loop over.
    std::string_view view(outHash, sizeOfHash);

    // Loop over the string.
    for(unsigned char val: view) {
        // Convert to `unsigned char` to make sure you don't print
        // negative numbers. Then convert from there to `int` so that
        // the `std::hex will kick in and convert to hex value.
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(val);
    }   
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on C++ wrapper around Windows Crypto API & CNG which I am using in my projects. I plan to move all of it to github but for now it is just a work in progress, but you can find it useful for Crypto basics like HEX / Base64 encode / decode etc.

https://github.com/m4x1m1l14n/Crypto

You can use Crypto::Hex::Encode() method to achieve what you want.

```
#include <Crypto\Hex.hpp>
#include <Crypto\Random.hpp>

using namespace m4x1m1l14n;

char arr[] = { 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0x99, 0x00 };

encoded = Crypto::Hex::Encode(arr, sizeof(arr));

/* encoded = "aabbccdd9900" */
```

Also you can use wrapper for MD5 which is located in Hash namespace, like this. (If you are not using large amount of data)

```
#include <Crypto\Hex.hpp>
#include <Crypto\Hash.hpp>

using namespace m4x1m1l14n;

encoded = Crypto::Hex::Encode(Crypto::Hash::MD5("Whatever you want to hash"));
```